# Hiding privately mutable properties behind immutable interfaces in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, properties, immutability, mutable

So, what I basically want to ask is whether the following code is safe (not whether it works, because it does). I.e, will the public getter override the synthesized getter of the actionLog property [which is of a different type]?

.h file:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
- (NSArray*) actionLog;
@end
```

.m file:

```
@interface SomeClass ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* actionLog;
@end

@implementation SomeClass
...
@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not only OK, it is exactly why class extensions were created in the first place!

Yes, there will be a single automatically synthesized ivar and pair of getter/setter methods generated as expected.

---

Sorry -- missed the `NSArray` vs. `NSMutableArray` part.  No, you can't do that;  the types must be the same.

*However*, you don't want to return your mutable array anyway.   First, the caller *might* modify it (a bug).  But, more importantly, the caller will assume that the contents are immutable as implied by the API) and, thus, when that array's contents change out from under the caller, it may cause issue (example;  caller can reasonably assume that the result of `count` will be stable and can be cached).

Comment: Extra thanks for the valuable insight about the initial reason for having categories!

Comment: I now experience that it doesn't seem to work to have NSArray* in the public interface and NSMutableArray* in the private. Did you notice this difference in my code, or did you just answer to the use of the readonly property label?

Comment: I didn't think about that "sending mutating messages to immutable object" problem. Great thanks for that insight! Just to clarify; I assume that what I'm supposed to do is to return a copy of the array in the "- (NSArray*) actionLog" method. And one more thing, I now see that I had the readonly actionLog property in the code above; that is wrong and I will now edit it, I only wanted to have the explicit getter in the public interface.

Answer (score 1):

By backing the property with a mutable ivar, like this:

.h file:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *actionLog;

@end
```

.m file:

```
@implementation SomeClass{
    NSMutableArray* _actionLog;
}

-(void)insertAction:(Action *)action{
    if(!_actionLog){
        _actionLog = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [_actionLog addObject:action];
}

@end
```